# How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python

Tags: python, string, numbers, number-formatting

How do I format a floating number to a fixed width with the following requirements:

1. Leading zero if n < 1
2. Add trailing decimal zero(s) to fill up fixed width
3. Truncate decimal digits past fixed width
4. Align all decimal points

For example:

```
% formatter something like '{:06}'
numbers = [23.23, 0.123334987, 1, 4.223, 9887.2]

for number in numbers:
    print formatter.format(number)
```

The output would be like

```
  23.2300
   0.1233
   1.0000
   4.2230
9887.2000
```

Answer (score 702, accepted):

```py
numbers = [23.23, 0.1233, 1.0, 4.223, 9887.2]                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                
for x in numbers:                                                                                                                                                                               
    print("{:10.4f}".format(x))
```

prints

```
   23.2300
    0.1233
    1.0000
    4.2230
 9887.2000
```

The format specifier inside the curly braces follows the [Python format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). Specifically, in this case, it consists of the following parts:

- The *empty string* before the colon means "take the next provided argument to `format()`" – in this case the `x` as the only argument.
- The `10.4f` part after the colon is the [format specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).
- The `f` denotes fixed-point notation.
- The `10` is the total width of the field being printed, lefted-padded by spaces.
- The `4` is the number of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: So I understand that the 4f represents limiting the decimals to 4 (with trailing zeros), but what does the 10 mean? Does that mean this formatting won't work with integers greater than 9999999999 (ten 9's)? Just curious.

Comment: `10.4` means a width of 10 characters and a precision of 4 decimal places.

Comment: @hobbes3: `10` is the minimum field width, i.e. the minimum length of the printed string.  Numbers are by default right-aligned and padded with spaces -- see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for more details.

Comment: For Pythons prior to 2.7: `("%0.4f" % x).rjust(10)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Or simply `"%10.4f" % x`.  In Python 2.6, you can also use `"{0:10.4f}".format(x)`.

Comment: That 10.4 means `12345.7890` and not `1234567890.0000` is the ghost of FORTRAN.  Almost as old a curse as QWERTY.

Comment: This doesn't work for negative floats though - the sign offsets the decimal column. Adding a leading space works though: `("% 10.4f" % x)`, or `"{: 10.4f}".format(x)`

Comment: @naught101 Not sure what you mean; the code in this answer [works perferctly fine for negative numbers](https://ideone.com/Vq5MCY).

Comment: @SvenMarnach Ah, yeah, I read the docs wrong. The 10 is the total length, so it does work in this case. I had a case last week where it wasn't working, but it's because I was using the wrong number before the `.`. Still, the space adds a leading space to positive numbers, which may be useful, although I can't think of an example right now..

Comment: If numbers include signed floats then the floating point doesn't stay at the same column. Is there a way to also consider the negative sign?

Comment: @PouJa The sign does not affect the position of the decimal point ([example](https://ideone.com/TP3QvH)). The only problem that can occur is that the number does not fit within the total width you alotted for it, in which case you should increase that number (`10` in the code above).

Comment: warning, this doesn't work with very large numbers, for example `print("{:10.10000f}".format(math.sqrt(666))[99])` prints 0, but that's not correct, it's supposed to be 1. and [100] prints prints 0, that's also wrong, [100] is supposed to be 9.

Comment: @hanshenrik This is due to the limited precision of floating-point numbers. I'ts not related to how formatting works. In other words, `math.sqrt(666)` is only an approximation to the actual square root of 666. This approaximation is then exactly represented during string formatting. The 99. and 100. decimal place of the approximation actually are exactly 0.

Comment: A very large number may still result in a string longer than otherwise, so this isn't truly "fixed width" (depending on your interpretation of the term).

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev That's in the nature of the problem. If you use a column of fixed width, there may be numbers that are too wide to fit in.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You can use scientific notation in that case. I think this is a solvable problem if you assume some bare minimum (5-7) of characters. I posted a draft of a function which attempts to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77674663/21501

Answer (score 234):

It has been a few years since this was answered, **but as of Python 3.6** ([PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)) you could use the new `f-strings`:

```
numbers = [23.23, 0.123334987, 1, 4.223, 9887.2]

for number in numbers:
    print(f'{number:9.4f}')
```

**Prints:**

```
  23.2300
   0.1233
   1.0000
   4.2230
9887.2000
```

Comment: Note that the width also includes dot character. So if you specify 9 to be width, 1 will be used for printing the dot, the other 8 will be for printing digits and spaces.

Comment: A very large number may still result in a string longer than otherwise, so this isn't truly "fixed width" (depending on your interpretation of the term).

Answer (score 49):

In python3 the following works:

```
>>> v=10.4
>>> print('% 6.2f' % v)
  10.40
>>> print('% 12.1f' % v)
        10.4
>>> print('%012.1f' % v)
0000000010.4
```

Comment: This has changed in the last 4 years, now `%` formatting is the oldest method of formatting. For several reasons using `str.format` or `f-strings` is preferred over `%`. Previously when it was only `str.format`, people had some reasons but `f-strings` fixed that hole. [format mini-language docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), [str.format examples from docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) and [f-string literals examples in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)

Answer (score 14):

You can also left pad with zeros. For example if you want `number` to have 9 characters length, left padded with zeros use:

`print('{:09.3f}'.format(number))`

Thus, if `number = 4.656`, the output is: `00004.656`

For your example the output will look like this:

```
numbers  = [23.2300, 0.1233, 1.0000, 4.2230, 9887.2000]
for x in numbers: 
    print('{:010.4f}'.format(x))
```

prints:

```
00023.2300
00000.1233
00001.0000
00004.2230
09887.2000
```

One example where this may be useful is when you want to properly list filenames in alphabetical order. I noticed in some linux systems, the number is: 1,10,11,..2,20,21,...

Thus if you want to enforce the necessary numeric order in filenames, you need to left pad with the appropriate number of zeros.

Answer (score 14):

Using [f-string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
>>> number = 12.34
>>> print(f"{number}")
12.34
>>> print(f"{number:10f}")
 12.340000
>>> print(f"{number:10.4f}")
   12.3400
```

The `10.4f` after the colon `:` is the [format specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), with 10 being the width in characters of the whole number (including spaces), and the second number 4 being the number of decimal places, and the `f` standing for floating-point number.

It's also possible to use variables instead of hard-coding the width and the number of decimal places:

```
>>> number = 12.34
>>> width = 10
>>> decimals = 4
>>> print(f"{number:{width}.{decimals}f}")
   12.3400
```

Comment: Is there any reason why "print(f"{number:5f}")" doesn't work as expected? It outputs 9 symbols ("12.340000"). Looks like 9 is the smallest width? But why? At the same time, adding the number of digits after decimal separator (5.2f) prints a string of 5 symbols as expected.

Comment: @Roman According to the documentation for the `f` type, "With no precision given, uses a precision of 6 digits after the decimal point for float,". So `print(f"number:99f")` will print a number that is at least 99 spaces wide, defaulting to six decimal places, since no precision was given, only width.

Answer (score 12):

See Python 3.x [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
IDLE 3.5.1   
numbers = ['23.23', '.1233', '1', '4.223', '9887.2']

for x in numbers:  
    print('{0: >#016.4f}'. format(float(x)))  

     23.2300
      0.1233
      1.0000
      4.2230
   9887.2000
```

Answer (score 12):

This will print `76.66`:

```py
print("Number: ", f"{76.663254: .2f}")
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.

```
GPA = 2.5
print(" %6.1f " % GPA)
```

`6.1f` means after the dots 1 digits show if you print 2 digits after the dots you should only `%6.2f` such that `%6.3f` 3 digits print after the point.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar for arrays. That helped me

```
some_array_rounded=np.around(some_array, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that most answers here can return a string longer than the indicated width, if the number is still very large.

If you absolutely need the resulting string to be exactly a certain number of characters, because e.g. you want to display it in a fixed-width font in a table or other context where the number of characters is critical, I don't think there is something built-in for this. A custom function which switches over to scientific notation to save space is possible, i.e. something like the following:

```py
def fpstr(n, width, sign=''):
    n = float(n)
    attempts = []
    def v(s):
        if len(s) != width:
            return
        try:
            float(s)
        except Exception:
            return
        attempts.append(s)

    for w in reversed(range(width)):
        v("{:{}0.0{}f}".format(n, sign, w))

    for w in reversed(range(width)):
        v("{:{}0.0{}g}".format(n, sign, w))

    for w in reversed(range(width)):
        v("{:{}{}g}".format(n, sign, w).rjust(width))

    for w in reversed(range(width)):
        v("{:{}.{}e}".format(n, sign, w).rjust(width))

    if not attempts:
        return "#" * width

    best_attempt = attempts[0]
    for attempt in attempts[1:]:
        if abs(n - float(attempt)) < abs(n - float(best_attempt)):
            best_attempt = attempt
    return best_attempt
```

(This is a draft so leaving this as a community wiki to allow future improvement.)

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the options like

1. `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.4f}'.format`
2. `pd.set_option('display.float_format', str)`
3. `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: f'%.{len(str(x%1))-2}f' % x)`
4. `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)`

but nothing worked for me.

so while assigning the variable/value (`var1`) to a variable (say `num1`) I used `round(val,5)` like

```
num1 = round(var1,5)
```

This is a crude method as you have to use this round function in each assignment.  But this ensures you control on how it happens and get what you want.