# Printing 2 numbers before comma

Tags: python, printing, precision

I want to print numbers with precision to 2 digits before dot and 3 after.

Example:

```
1232.352232  
9.1
```

will show:

```
32.352  
09.100
```

I know that

```
print "%.3f" % 32.352
```

will show me 3 digits after dot but how to get 2 digits before dot with 0 if that is shorter than 2 digits?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a total width for the output; if you include a leading 0 then the number will be padded with zeros to match that minimum width:

```
"%06.3f" % float_number
```

Demo:

```
>>> for float_number in (1232.352232, 9.1):
...     print "%06.3f" % float_number
... 
1232.352
09.100
```

Note that the number is a **minimum** width! If you need to truncate the floating point number itself, you'll need to use slicing:

```
("%06.3f" % float_number)[-6:]
```

This will truncate string to remove characters from the start if longer than 6:

```
>>> for float_number in (1232.352232, 9.1):
...     print ("%06.3f" % float_number)[-6:]
... 
32.352
09.100
```

You may want to look at the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) too; this function lets you apply the [same formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) as the [`str.format()` formatting method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) and [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings); the syntax is basically the same for floats:

```
>>> for float_number in (1232.352232, 9.1):
...     formatted = format(float_number, '06.3f')
...     print(formatted[-6:], formatted)
...
32.352 1232.352
09.100 09.100
```

Comment: I tried to put "%02.3f" %1.1234 and it doesn't return me 01,123

Comment: @SebastianB: that's because the first number must be set to the *total* width. Include the decimals! `"%06.3f" % 1.1234` works.

Comment: Is there a concise way to save this to a string variable?

Comment: @Aaronrobeson: I'm not sure what you mean. The `str % ...` operation returns a new string object, just assign that new object to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "9,1"

def displayNum(num):
    f,s = num.strip().split(',')
    f = '0'*(2-len(f))+f if len(f) < 2 else f[-2:]
    s = s + '0'*(3-len(s)) if len(s) < 3 else s[:3]
    return ",".join([f,s])

print(displayNum(x))

09,100
```