# Formatting floating point number in Python with padding of 0s

Tags: python, floating-point

Python, version 2.7.3 on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04

I have a floating point number between 0 and 99.99.
I need to print it as a string in this format:

WW_DD

where WW are whole digits and DD are the rounded, 2 digits past the decimal place.
The string needs to be padded with 0s front and back so that it always the same format.

Some examples:

```
0.1    -->  00_10
1.278  -->  01_28
59.0   -->  59_00
```

I did the following:

```
def getFormattedHeight(height):

    #Returns the string as:  XX_XX   For example:  01_25
    heightWhole = math.trunc( round(height, 2) )
    heightDec = math.trunc( (round(height - heightWhole, 2))*100 )
    return "{:0>2d}".format(heightWhole) + "_" + "{:0>2d}".format(heightDec)
```

which works well except for the number 0.29, which formats to 00_28.

Can someone find a solution that works for all numbers between 0 and 99.99?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Format floating point number with padding zeros:**

```
numbers = [0.0, 0.1, 0.29, 1.278, 59.0, 99.9]
for x in numbers:
    print("{:05.2f}".format(x).replace(".","_"))
```

Which prints:

```
00_00
00_10
00_29
01_28
59_00
99_90
```

The `:05` means 'pad with zeros using five places' and `.2f` means 'force show 2 digits after the decimal point'.  For background on formatting numbers see: https://pyformat.info/#number.

Hat-tip: [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Comment: Simple. Elegant.  Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your original solution works if you calculate `heightDec` this way:

```
heightDec = int(round((height - heightWhole)*100, 0))
```

First multiply by 100 and then round and convert to int.