# how do i add a phrase to a float (decimal) number in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm working on a code to divide numbers and its dealing with if statements and stuff. What I have currently is:

```
num= int(input( "Enter the numerator: "))  

den= int(input( "Enter the denominator: "))   

if (den==0):  
    print ("Error - cannot divide by zero")  
else:  
    print ("Decimal: ") + (num/den)
```

Well, my issue is on that last line of code. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I've tried float, str, and int and every time it gives me an issue.

Comment: `print("Decimal:", num/den)` alternatively look at `str.format()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There is little syntax error in the last line of the code. Also, covert float to string before concatenation else it will traceback with a TypeError.

```
num= int(input( "Enter the numerator: "))  

den= int(input( "Enter the denominator: "))   

if (den==0):  
    print ("Error - cannot divide by zero")  
else:  
    print ("Decimal: " + str(num/den))  # Check syntax. Convert float to string
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

from **future** import division

num ,den = map(int,raw_input().split()) #enter space separate input

if den==0:

```
print "Error - cannot divide by zero"
```

else:

```
print "Decimal: " + str(num/den)
```