# Python - Rounding to two specific digits EXACTLY

Tags: python-2.7

The number I have = 52.003

The number I want = 52.00

The number I get after rounding to 2 decimal places:

```
    round(52.003, 2)
    >>> 52.0
```

How do I keep the second digit without Python automatically rounding it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the format() function in Python.

```
"{0:.2f}".format(round(52.003, 2))
```

You can also use the string formatting operator.

```
'%.2f' % 52.003
```

Comment: Thank you. I do wish there was a way to do it without having to convert it to a string though.

Comment: @Dman42 to view an value, it is *always* converted to a string, the default just wasn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the output format like this:

```
a = 52.003
print "%.2f" % a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function :

```
import numpy as np
Round = lambda x, n: eval('"%.' + str(int(n)) + 'f" % ' + repr(x))
a = Round(52.003,2)
print a
>>> 52.00
```

Just indicate the number of decimals you want as a kwarg. However the result will be a string.