# How do I limit the length of a float and not just it's decimals?

Tags: python

I'm working on a script that needs to output numbers in a precision determined by length and not just decimal places. Let's say I want a max of 7 decimals but whole numbers above 7 digits are ok although they can't have decimals if the total amount of digits is 7 or higher.

So the rules are:

```
- If a float has more than 7 digits of whole numbers, it loses it's decimals
- If a float has less than 7 digits of whole numbers, it gets a length of 7 total digits including decimals
- If a floats has no digits of whole numbers, it keeps 7 decimals
```

For example:

```
a = 10000.02
b = 1.000002
c = 100000000000
```

are all correct.

How do I handle numbers (all `float`) in this format?

For example:

```
d = 892432589.54680
e = 382.39810758264057251
f = 452545871.1643548
g = 10254.968743541742
h = 165783438364325.126
```

I was thinking about something along the lines of:

```
length_of_number = len(str(x))
    if length_of_number > 7:
        x.round(0)
    else:
        x.round(7 - length_of_number)
```

but then I get in trouble with situations like

```
x= 0.5313231568943218748
```

because the whole `float` is longer than 7 digits.

What to do?

Edit for asked examples:

```
12345678 is ok
1234567.1 is ok (but 1234567.12 not)
1.12345678 would become 1.123456
```

Comment: You can't use commas like that in numeric literals.  [Instead, as of Python 3.6, you can use underscores `_` to group digits in numeric literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Comment: @patrick Oh sorry, I probably did that to make it more readable for humans. Forgetting that it's not how I handle the actual numbers in the script. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: @supersam654 I don't want my decimals to have a fixed width, I want to have a maximum amount of decimals determined by the length of the float.

Comment: Are you looking at the number of digits, or the number of characters when truncating to seven?  does `-0.12345678` get truncated to `-0.123456`, `-0.1234567`, or `-0.1234`?

Comment: I'm having a problem understanding the expected results. Could you provide your expected outputs for `12345678`, `1234567.1`, and `1.12345678`, please?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Negative numbers are not an issue in this case. Just the digits.

Comment: Why is `1234567.1` okay? It has 8 digits even though there are 7 whole numbers? In the later sample you said `1.123456` should be the expected result of `1.12345678`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want, but perhaps this can help you?

```
round(num_here, 7)
```

From the documentation:

> Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its input.
>
> For the built-in types supporting [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) , values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits; if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both `round(0.5)` and `round(-0.5)` are 0, and `round(1.5)` is 2). Any integer value is valid for ndigits (positive, zero, or negative). The return value is an integer if called with one argument, otherwise of the same type as number.
>
> For a general Python object number, `round(number, ndigits)` delegates to `number.__round__(ndigits)`.
>
> > **Note:** The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected `2.68`. This is not a bug: it's a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can't be represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations for more information](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking can be solved in how you determine your length and also by finding if there is a decimal in your string or not.  For instance if you said

```
>>>a = 1325.6326
>>>len(str(a).split(".")[0])
4
```

This will give you the length of all your numbers to the left of the decimal place.

```
>>>b = '.' in str(a)
>>>print(b)
True
```

And this will tell you if there is a decimal place in your number.

Answer (score 0):

```
def truncate(n):
    s = str(n)
    is_decimal = '.' in s
    if len(s) <= 7 + is_decimal:
        return s
    if not is_decimal:
        return s
    fore, aft = s.split('.', 1)
    if len(fore) >= 7:
        return fore
    if n < 1:
        return '{:.7f}'.format(n)
    return f'{{:.{7-len(fore)}f}}'.format(n)
```

Here's one version, using string formatting to truncate the decimals.  It turns out that string formatting actually rounds, instead of dropping characters, so string slicing may work better for you

```
def truncate(n):
    s = str(n)
    is_decimal = '.' in s
    if len(s) <= 7 + is_decimal:
        return s
    if not is_decimal:
        return s
    fore, aft = s.split('.', 1)
    if len(fore) >= 7:
        return fore
    if n < 1:
        return '.' + aft[:7]
    return '{}.{}'.format(fore, aft[:7-len(fore)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I change your code slightly and turned it into a function to make it easier to test.

```
num = [892432589.54680,
  382.39810758264057251,
  452545871.1643548,
  10254.968743541742,
  165783438364325.126,
  0.5313231568943218748]

def trunc_num(x):
  num_int = int(x)
  length_of_number = len(str(num_int))
  if length_of_number >= 7:
    return num_int
  else:
    return round(x, 7 - length_of_number)

for n in num:
  print(trunc_num(n))
```

By changing the number into an `int` the decimals are dropped and we can check the length of the number with out the decimal in the way. If the `int` is greater than 7 digits we just return the `int` else we round the number as you were trying before.

Output

```
892432589
382.3981
452545871
10254.97
165783438364325
0.531323
```

If you need to account for negative numbers than you can just add `lstrip` after converting it to a string.

```
length_of_number = len(str(num_int).lstrip('-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super simple version using string slicing:

```
def seven(x):
    ret = lambda x: float(x) if '.' in str(x) else int(x)
    return ret(str(x)[:max(str(x).find('.'), 8 + ('-' in str(x)))].strip('.'))
```

## Output:

```
<class 'int'>           892432590
<class 'int'>          -892432590
<class 'float'>          382.3981
<class 'float'>         -382.3981
<class 'int'>           452545871
<class 'int'>          -452545871
<class 'float'>          10254.97
<class 'float'>         -10254.97
<class 'int'>     165783438364325
<class 'int'>    -165783438364325
<class 'float'>          0.531323
<class 'float'>         -0.531323
```

An alternative using `str.format()`:

```
def seven(x):
    ret = lambda x: float(x) if '.' in x else int(x)
    return ret('{:.{cutoff}f}'.format(x, cutoff=7 - min(str(x).find('.') - ('-' in str(x)), 7)))
```