# What does 10f in ephem data mean?

Tags: python, string-formatting

What does 10f mean in the line `>>> print('%.10f' % yh.earth_distance)`?

Here is an example where it is used:

```
>>> line = "C/2002 Y1 (Juels-Holvorcem),e,103.7816,166.2194,128.8232,242.5695,0.0002609,0.99705756,0.0000,04/13.2508/2003,2000,g  6.5,4.0"
>>> yh = ephem.readdb(line)
>>> yh.compute('2007/10/1')
>>> print('%.10f' % yh.earth_distance)
14.8046731949
>>> print(yh.mag)
23.96
```

Comment: https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting

Comment: 10 digits after the decimal.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ephem, this is formatting for python strings. In this particular case — "use 10 digits after floating(decimal) point"