# How can I make this produce nice columns but maintain the 2 decimal places?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to produce two columns of data in a table that also have a float output with 2 decimal places. I can do either or at the moment but not both. How can I simply combine the formats of these two?

```py
#Code that shows 2 decimal places

def c2f():
    print("Celsius","Fahrenheit")
    for i in [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]:
        c = i
        f = 9 / 5 * i + 32
        table_data = [
            [c,f], 
        ]
        for row in table_data:
            print("{: .2f} {: .2f}".format(*row))
c2f()

#Code that formats data into columns

def c2f():
    print("Celsius","Fahrenheit")
    for i in [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]:
        c = i
        f = 9 / 5 * i + 32
        table_data = [
            [c,f], 
        ]
        for row in table_data:
            print("{: <20} {: <20}".format(*row))
c2f()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this:

```
print("{:9}|".format("%.2f" % 12))
```

output :

```
12.00    |
```