# I have problem with confusion_matrix Python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I made confusion_matrix in Python, but If I print it as array it is OK I see numbers: 145, 23, 31, 69, But if I want to show it on seaborn heatmap I have: 14e+02, 23, 31, 69 so all is ok but why I have 14e+02 instead of 145 ? Hep me please, it looks unsightly. Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Use [sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix)

Comment: how can I use it? could you convert my code with your suggestion ?

Comment: The following example [Confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py)

Comment: For future reference, it's easier to get answers if you post your code as text. Posting a screenshot of the code usually isn't helpful. While the screenshot is useful in this case to show the plot the code generates, I'd still suggest editing the question to include the code as text too. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the format:

```py
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=True, fmt='d') # you can use d if you have integers
```

Comment: Wow, perfect, it works, but how it works ? what is fmt = "d" ?

Comment: It's a format string. [See this answer for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8885688/11751294)