# In python how can I have a float with two decimal places (as a float)?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a float  let's say

```
x = 2.00
```

I want to send that as json

```
message = { 'x': 2.00 }
```

But when I do

```
print(message)
```

I see that python has dropped the last decimal place. How can I keep the float at two decimal places? I understand that 2.00 and 2.0 are not different but it's a requirement that I send that exact number (two decimal places included) (I have tried the Decimal class, it still acts the same and I need to send it as a float not a string). Thanks in advance.

Comment: This cannot be done in `json` as there is no requirement on the formatting of floats. This would have to be done after the `json` has been decoded again, by formatting as a string. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem recently, and tried the solution given in this thread by @kederrac. His solution mostly worked for me (Python 3.11), but did not handle nested dictionaries or lists. In case anyone else has the same issue, here is an extended version of his JSON encoder class which should handle a greater number of cases

```
import json

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, float):
            return format(obj, '.2f')

        if isinstance(obj, dict) and len(obj) > 0:
            result = '{'
            for key, value in obj.items():
                encoded_value = self.encode(value)
                result += f'"{key}": {encoded_value}, '
            result = result[:-2] + '}'
            return result

        if isinstance(obj, list) and len(obj) > 0:
            result = '['
            for value in obj:
                encoded_value = self.encode(value)
                result += encoded_value + ', '
            result = result[:-2] + ']'
            return result
        
        return json.JSONEncoder.encode(self, obj)

message = { 'x': 2.00 } 
message_2 = {"x": {"y": [1.3, 1, .4123], "z": 2.0}}
print(json.dumps(message, cls=MyEncoder))
print(json.dumps(data, cls=MyEncoder))
```

Output:

```
{"x": 2.00}
{"x": {"y": [1.30, 1, 0.41], "z": 2.00}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a specialized library for serializing floats and retaining precision. Protocol Buffers is one such library (protocol)you can define your own JSON encoder class: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3.

Answer (score 0):

you can define your own JSON encoder class:

```
import json

message = {'x': 2.00}

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):

        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            result = '{'
            for key, value in obj.items():
                if isinstance(value, float):
                    encoded_value = format(value, '.2f')
                else:
                    encoded_value = json.JSONEncoder.encode(self, value)

                result += f'"{key}": {encoded_value}, '

            result = result[:-2] + '}'
            return result
        return json.JSONEncoder.encode(self, obj)

print(json.dumps(message, cls=MyEncoder))
```

output:

```
{"x": 2.00}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom JSONEncoder by:

1. Encoding the number as a 2dp string with some surrounding characters.
2. Using regex to strip out the special characters and the quotes.

Here's an example using Decimal:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from json import JSONEncoder
import json
import re


def to_json(value: dict) -> str:
    class DecimalEncoder(JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, obj):
            if type(obj) is Decimal:
                return f"Decimal({obj:.2f})"
            else:
                return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

    json_string = json.dumps(value, cls=DecimalEncoder)
    json_string = re.sub(r'"Decimal\((.*?)\)"', r"\1", json_string)

    return json_string


before = {
    "amount": Decimal("2.1"),
}

after = to_json(before)

print(before)
print(after)
```

And the result:

```
{'amount': Decimal('2.1')}
{"amount": 2.10}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example:

```
a=2.00
print ("{0:.2f}".format(a))
```

Comment: Doesn't explain how to pass a decimal value to JSON and retain same numbers after the decimal point.