# Fix decimal points in python

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a float `17.3743` and I need to put in the format `17.37`, using `"{:.2f}".format(17.3743)` works fine, but when the input have only one digit then it does nothing instead of fixing 2 decimais points, for example `13.3` do not result in `13.30` as I really needed. How can I solve this?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python

Comment: I've just tried `print("{:.2f}".format(13.3))` and it DID result in 13.30 exactly the way you want. Full example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your suggestion works fine to me:

```
>>> print("{:.2f}".format(123.1123123123))
123.11
>>> print("{:.2f}".format(123.1))
123.10
```

Taken straight from the Python 3.8 IDLE.

What's not working about it for you?
What's the context you are trying to use it in?

It seems like something else might be your problem.

Comment: Yep, just tried myself on 3.8.2 and 2.7.13, both work exactly the way OP wants with the exact format string the OP offers.

Comment: As an addendum, it works without any decimals at all:

`>>> print("{:.2f}".format(123))
123.00
`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use format function like below:

```
format(number, '.2f')
```