# floating point precision display with python

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

When I run the following code:

```
for x in np.arange(0, 1, 0.1):
    print(x)
```

I get the following output?

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6000000000000001
0.7000000000000001
0.8
0.9
```

Why python does not display the numbers as expected? Is there any way to make python display the numbers as expected (i.e., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc.)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I changed the question. Please see the modified question.

Comment: Because the fourth element printed out is `0.1 * 3` and you're expecting `3.0 / 10`. These are not equal.  Floating point will be filled with surprises until you understand why they are not equal.

Comment: [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)