# What does this f mean in this sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, integer, format

I'm learning python from beginning and I don't understand the part where it says {2:.2f}. I know it is related to string format, but no more.

```
a = int(input('introduce a number: '))
b = int(input('introduce a number: '))

print('the result of {0} divided by {1} is {2:.2f}, and the result of {1} divided by {0} es {3}'.format(a, b, a/b, b/a))
```

Thanks!

Comment: This indicates a float rounded by two digits. See more information [here](https://thepythonguru.com/python-string-formatting/)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python. Note that the "f" you are asking about is a different "f" than the "f" in "f-string".

Answer (score 0):

it stands for floating point number, which means the amount of digits after the point