# Python - show float as a decimal in a print statement

Tags: python, decimal, python-3.9

I'm looking at prices of low-capitalization crypto meme coins. I want to format and show as a decimal in the print statement, up about 10 digits.  For example, the price of Saitama as shown on CoinGekco is $0.000000100861.

I don't understand if I'm using the Decimal library wrong, or if this is just a print/formatting issue.

```
from decimal import Decimal
# I think everything after the 7663 is irrelevant, this is a number I'm getting back 
# from a Uniswap API.  It could be the price in ETH, that is my next issue.
price_float = 2.08229530000000007663121204885725199461299350645049344166181981563568115234375E-11
price_decimal = Decimal(str(price_float))
print("float:", price_float) 
print("decimal:", price_decimal)
```

Results:

```
float: 2.0822953e-11
decimal: 2.0822953E-11
```

Desired Results:

```
float: 2.0822953e-11
decimal: .000000000020822953
```

But if I try an exponent less than 6 it seems to work:

```
price_float = 2.08229530000000007663121204885725199461299350645049344166181981563568115234375E-6
```

Result:

```
decimal: 0.0000020822953000000003
```

Update 1 - based on comment/suggestion: Trying the formatting string.
So a change to my question, do I need to bother with decimal at all, as long as I'm not adding numbers or maybe doing math on them?

```
print("float: {:10.14f}".format(price_float))
print("decimal: {:10.14f}".format(price_decimal))
```

Result:

```
float: 0.00000208229530
decimal: 0.00000208229530
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Comment: "Decimal" means "base 10". It doesn't mean "not scientific notation". `decimal.Decimal` internally uses a base 10 representation, but that doesn't mean it won't print in scientific notation.

Comment: Writing `price_float = 2.08229530000000007663` - never mind all the digits after that - is *utterly and completely useless*.  Floats simply do not store numbers with that many significant digits of precision; turning this float into a Decimal later does not magically restore the lost precision.  The only way to get the exact number into Decimal form is to pass it directly as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do that

```
print(f'{price_float:.20f}')
print(f'{price_float:.20E}')
```

Output

```
0.00000000002082295300
2.08229530000000007663E-11
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like `print("{:12.10f}".format(price_decimal))`. The output format is not controlled here by the decimal library