# i would like to print following pattern but i can't (I just started 10 days):

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

check the pattern of image, I want to make it.
I just can do bellow and not more:

```
n = 5
d = n
for x in range(1, n + 1):
    for y in range(1, n * 2 + 1):
        if (y >= d) != 0 and y <= n + x - 1:
            print(x * y, end=" ")
        elif y <= n:
            print("  ", end=" ")
        else:
            pass
    d -= 1
    print()
```

this is my output:

```
            5 
         8 10 12 
      9 12 15 18 21 
   8 12 16 20 24 28 32 
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
```

what should i do?
how should complete this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). Even if this isn't homework, most of the same advice applies, like "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first". See also [ask], which includes advice about writing a good title. You can [edit].

Comment: @anatolyg I don't see how that has anything to do with this...

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to continue your work with a second for loop. Also, note that there is no need for the `else: pass` clause.

```
n = 5
d = n
for x in range(1, n + 1):
    for y in range(1, n * 2 + 1):
        if (y >= d) != 0 and y <= n + x - 1:
            print(x * y, end=" ")
        elif y <= n:
            print("  ", end=" ")
    d -= 1
    print()
d+=2
for x in range(n+1, 2*n):
    for y in range(1, n * 2 + 1):
        if (y >= d) != 0 and y <= 3*n - x-1:
            print(x * y, end=" ")
        elif y <= n:
            print("  ", end=" ")
    d += 1
    print()
```

Which results in this output:

```
            5 
         8 10 12 
      9 12 15 18 21 
   8 12 16 20 24 28 32 
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 
   12 18 24 30 36 42 48 
      21 28 35 42 49 
         32 40 48 
            45
```

On the other hand, you might appreciate this script, which takes advantage of the `str.format` method.

```
n = 5
d = n
form = '{0:<4}'
rows = [[' '*4 for _ in range(2*n)] for _ in range(2*n)]
for x in range(1,n):
    for y in range(d,n+x):
        rows[x][y] = form.format(x*y)
    d-=1
for x in range(n, 2*n):
    for y in range(d, 3*n - x):
        rows[x][y] = form.format(x*y)
    d+=1
for row in rows:
    print(''.join(row))
```

Here's the resulting output:

```
                                        
                    5                   
                8   10  12              
            9   12  15  18  21          
        8   12  16  20  24  28  32      
    5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  
        12  18  24  30  36  42  48      
            21  28  35  42  49          
                32  40  48              
                    45
```

You might find it interesting to see how the outputs change as n is varied.

We could also get the same result as the above without the `d` parameter:

```
n = 5
form = '{0:<4}'
rows = [[' '*4 for _ in range(2*n+1)] for _ in range(2*n+1)]
for x in range(1,n):
    for y in range(n-x+1,n+x):
        rows[x][y] = form.format(x*y)
for x in range(n, 2*n):
    for y in range(x-n+1, 3*n - x):
        rows[x][y] = form.format(x*y)
for row in rows:
    print(''.join(row))
```